# Pinch gestures in WP8

Tags: windows-phone-8, pinch

I'm trying to port existing wp7 app to wp8 and there is problem with maps. Map is made from 6 tiles. Everything is working well, but pinching is terrible. Works much worse than on WP7.

Anything changed in WP8? What I have found is small information from microsoft presentation which says that in WP8 some things from pinch and strech were improved

Extends the ManipulationDeltaEventArgs class
PinchManipulation property
Provides center point for the original and current gesture

Answer (score 0):

my 0.02$: On WP8 you should move from Bing Maps to using the new Nokia Maps control @ http://www.developer.nokia.com/Resources/Library/Lumia/guide-to-the-maps.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have just ported your app to WP8 from WP7 then everything should work as before. The only problem might be if you have hardcoded some display resolution values in your app, for computing the pinch gestures for example, and the app in now running on device with 720p display - it has height 853px instead of 800px.
Anyway as Justin noted you can switch to new Nokia maps in WP8, but you can still use Bing maps as well, although they are deprecated on WP8. You just have to reference new WP8 Bing maps library in folder:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v8.0\Libraries

Comment: maybe I didnt underline it enough but I have map control but inside there is my control with map picture divided to 6 tiles. so there is no use of bing/nokia maps. just gesture listener works terrible